# WSDL Merge (External Entity)

Tags: apex, wsdl, wsdl2apex, partner-wsdl

I am trying to Merge(Consolidate) multiple WSDL into a single WSDL file .

Example :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions name="ExternalServiceFacade" targetNamespace="http://www.materialise.be/eRP" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://www.materialise.be/eRP" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:i0="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
  <wsdl:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/" location="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc?wsdl=wsdl0" /> 
 <wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/Imports">
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://www.materialise.be/eRP" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" /> 
  <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eRP.ExternalService.Model" /> 
  </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="IExternalService_CreateCustomer_InputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateCustomer" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="IExternalService_CreateCustomer_OutputMessage">
  <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:CreateCustomerResponse" /> 
  </wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IExternalService">
<wsdl:operation name="CreateCustomer">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/CreateCustomer" message="tns:IExternalService_CreateCustomer_InputMessage" /> 
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.materialise.be/eRP/ICustomerService/CreateCustomerResponse" message="tns:IExternalService_CreateCustomer_OutputMessage" /> 
  </wsdl:operation>
- <wsdl:service name="ExternalServiceFacade">
- <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IExternalService" binding="i0:BasicHttpBinding_IExternalService">
  <soap:address location="https://sv7767.si-servers.com/Streamics-test/External.svc" /> 
  </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

Can you please let me know how can i Consolidate the multiple  in to Single WSDL file.

Any other Tool that can do this Merge?.

Comment: Donald, it doesn’t feel that this is a question about Salesforce. Did you need to merge wsdl files or is your need within a Salesforce org?

Comment: hi Sebastian,I need merge the WSDL files and needs to be validated by salesfroce apex2wsdl.Sorry for late response  to the post.Can you please point me in the right direction if any tools are available to do this activity.